# Technique to find first principal parts when later parts change spelling? E.g. find 'nanciscor' from 'nactus'

Tags: verbs, morphology, orthography, conjugation, dictionary

I am tutoring a friend who is preparing for a graduate school translation exam, of the "unseen passage, dictionary allowed, time limit imposed, be accurate" variety.

We came across *nacti* in paragraph 22 [here](http://w2.vatican.va/content/paul-vi/la/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-vi_enc_25071968_humanae-vitae.html). I found *nanciscor* pretty quickly, and she didn't.

When I tried to explain how I knew to check that spelling, I was at a loss.

Here's my real question: Is there any sort of good procedure I could give a student that would allow them to make a list of probable first principal part spellings, given later principal parts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be able to generate a list of candidates, one should know some common ways to produce different principal parts from a given stem.

To produce the present stem (the first principal part as you call it) one might add a nasal before the last consonant.
To produce the perfect stem one might reduplicate the first syllable, with possibility for vowel gradation.
To produce the perfect participle stem one might add a *t*, with possibility for assimilation in the preceding consonant.
Using these rules to the stem *tag-*, one obtains the stems *tang-*, *tetig-* and *tact-*.

You can find more possible ways to play with the stems in many Latin grammars, and I will not attempt to list them here.
Instead, let me try to detail the process I would take to find *nancisci* from *nacti*.
First, the perfect participle stem seems to be *nact-*.
There is no sign of reduplication (we couldn't remove a syllable anyway since there is only one — and reduplication should only appear in the active perfect stem anyway), so the present stem might be *nac-*.
It is possible that the *t* has caused some assimilation, so it could be *nag-* or *nah-* instead.
There could also be a nasal in the present stem, so also *nanc-* and *nang-* might be possible.
If you manage to conclude that one option is *nanc-*, you will find the verb in a dictionary; you won't need to guess the incohative *-isc-*.

In short:
To see the first principal form, know the rules to generate later principal forms and try to guess which ones may have been used.
If I see a perfect participle of a new verb, I will not know the first principal part for certain, but I can make a number of guesses.
And know your irregular verbs — they may also come with prefixes.